# hyperref Warning: Draft mode on

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to get `hyperref` to work with `pdflatex`, but I'm getting the error `hyperref Warning: Draft mode on` and since all hyperrefs are disabled in draft mode, there are no links being created.

I tried doing the following: `\usepackage[final]{hyperref}` but still no success.

I'm using document class `book`: `\documentclass{book}` so nowhere do I say that I want draft enabled.

Tried compiling on two different machines with `TexnicCenter` using `pdflatex`(LaTeX=>PDF).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make a complete example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Working on it.. creating just a simple `MWE` works, so gotta figure out what breaks it.. :)

Comment: Look in the log-file if another package loads hyperref before you do it. Or if you load a package which could interact with hyperref.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Maybe this is the culpit? `\RequirePackage[unicode=true,draft,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}`

Comment: It's quite strange that a package loads `hyperref` with the `draft` option turned on.

Comment: @egreg, It's a package for CreateSpace publishing, so you don't want hyperrefs in the printed version.. But I do in the digital one!

Comment: Have you tried `\documentclass[final]{book}`?

Comment: @Karalga Yep. Problem was that another package included `hyperref` with draft mode.

Comment: @egreg Any package intended for paper print PDF/X must only use hyperref in draft mode. Not unusual!

Comment: If your book is print fiction, consider "novel" document class instead of book. Also consider KDP  instead of CS.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the documentation,

```
\hypersetup{final}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: where should I place it

Comment: @F505 Just before `\begin{document}` should do.

Answer (score 19):

Try:

```
\usepackage[draft=false]{hyperref}
```

Additionally, if you want to leave `hyperref` on for links but keep the same printed output, use something like:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks,draft=false]{hyperref}
```

When combined with a package like

```
\usepackage[obeyDraft]{todonotes}
```

it's really great and you can just change the `draft` option in the `\documentclass[]` and you can turn your 'to do' notes on and off really easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using your same code (with no relevant variations) and it works perfectly for me:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,draft]{book}
\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyDraft}{todonotes}
%PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks}{hyperref} % uncomment to hide links
\PassOptionsToPackage{final}{hyperref}
\usepackage{thesis-preamble}
\begin{document}
```

thesis-preamble.sty contains the line:

```
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

Also \RequirePackage[final]{hyperref} (and no PassOptionsToPackage) works.

Comment: This seems to be almost the same as in the already stated answers.

Comment: Other answers have minor differences, what I mean that I've done exactly the same thing as the asker, but it works for me