# Hyperref package isn't coloring url links

Tags: hyperref, input

Forgive me if this question has been answered elsewhere, but my googling was unable to find the solution.

Below is a MWE. The issue is that the link which I am trying to include on the copyright page is not being colored. I would like it to be colored. I think the issue might be due to the fact the I am using `\input` to include the content of the copyright page. I prefer to do this because I need to make several PDFs of this content but in different formats and keeping the content separate from the formatting is just easier for me. When I compile this with pdflatex the link for the url is black. The workaround [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79054/104214) is an option, however I would prefer to set this through the `hypersetup` environment.

document.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, draft]{memoir}
%% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% Package Configuration
\graphicspath{{../}}
\makeatletter
  \AtEndDocument{\hyxmp@find@metadata\hyxmp@embed@packet}
\makeatother
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdfauthor={An Author},
    pdftitle={A Title},
    pdfcopyright={Copyright © 2017 by An Author. Rights reservation statement.}
}
%%%% The documet
\begin{document}
\title{A Title}
\author{An Author}

\frontmatter
%% Copyright
\input{copyright.tex} 

%% Table of Contents, Introduction
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\part{A Part}
\lipsum
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

copyright.tex:

```
\begin{titlingpage}
\centering
Copyright \copyright ~ 2017 An Author.

Rights reservation statement.
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/}
\end{titlingpage}
```

Comment: try removing the `draft` mode in your `documentclass`. Works for me.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49277/what-does-the-draft-mode-change `hyperref` disables all linking features in draft mode

Comment: You can use the option `final` instead of `draft`(documentclass). Or set `\hypersetup{
final,
    colorlinks=true,...` see:https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66063/124842